# gamekit issue ios5 and ios6 device

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit

i'm developing a multiplayer card game. I used gamekit to do the network stuff but i encounter a problem:my app crash always on one client without log (it just freeze). After research and test I traced the source of the problem:
-server (ios 5 or ios 6) and client ios5 device = the app run perfectly
-server (ios 5 or ios 6) and client ios6 device = the app run perfectly
-server (ios 5 or ios 6) and client ios5 and ios6 = the app "freeze" on the iOS6 client.

the app freeze actually after the server receive the sign in response from all the client.of course the game still runs on the other devices.

```
peer (client with iOS 6) changed state 2
```

and the server show:

```
failed to send packet
```

i followed this tutorial :http://www.raywenderlich.com/12976/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-7
and I tested the final sample project from this tutorial and it crash exactly as my app do.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I do not think your application is locking up, I think it is just waiting for the packet (that is not getting there), is that the case? Or does it actually crash?

Comment: yes i believe that the packet is not getting to the client.but it only happen when i use clients with different iOS version.